# Get client locale using latex

Tags: languages, urls, locale

I want to detect client locale using Latex. I have this code:

```
\apiurl{https://wpf.test.com/<locale>/wpf}
```

But the output is:

```
https://wpf.test.com/¡locale¿/wpf
```

It should be `https://wpf.test.com/en/wpf` or `https://wpf.test.com/es/wpf` fro Spanish.

Do you know how I can implement this?

Comment: Do you want to detect the "locale" when compiling the document or during its visualization?

Comment: @PaulGaborit during visualization.

Comment: Most PDF viewers can't do this.